# Os cabelos "se revelam" pré-hidratados

Tags: significado-em-contexto

No texto seguinte, *"se revelam"* significa *"parecem"* ou *"ficam"*?

> Shampoo de limpeza suave que age sem agredir os fios, preparando-os para os próximos passos do tratamento de nutrição e reconstrução de X Y. Ao final da aplicação, os cabelos **se revelam** pré-hidratados, emolientes e maleáveis.

Comment: mostram-se, revelam-se, apresentam-se, qualquer um dos três.

Comment: Mas então isso significa que não "ficam" pré-hidratados, emolientes e maleáveis de verdade, senão apenas "parecem/mostram-se" assim, ou que? Obrigada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Revelar-se" é um verbo pronominal que significa

> [**manifestar-se; patentear-se; mostrar-se.**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Revelar-se)

As agências de propaganda, de um modo geral, evitam fazer afirmações categóricas sobre qualquer característica de seus produtos, para que não sejam acusadas de propaganda enganosa. Na tua frase...

> Ao final da aplicação, os cabelos se revelam pré-hidratados, emolientes e maleáveis.

...pode ser que os cabelos fiquem pré-hidratados, emolientes e maleáveis, mas a frase não afirma isso. É o mesmo que dizer "ela parece muito educada" que significa "ela se mostra muito educada". Pode ser que ela seja educada ou não.

Comment: Entendi. Agradeço muito sua resposta. Acho que devo verificar isso com o cliente, porque nem no restante do documeto evitaram fazer afirmações categóricas sobre as características como você falou. :) Probavelmente me falam que eu traduza a palavra como "ficam". Obrigada!!!